# Using global/system git-review config files (git-review.conf) is deprecated

Tags: python, git, gerrit, github-for-windows, wikimedia

Today I started to contribute for the *[Wikimedia **Gerrit** community](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/admin/projects/operations/mediawiki-config)* with *Git* and *GitHub Desktop* on my *Windows 10* (PC).

---

First I installed the `git-review` package with Pip:

```
$ pip install git-review
```

After I loged in, I cloning and creating a new branch with Git:

```
$ ssh suriyaa@gerrit.wikimedia.org -p 29418

$ git clone ssh://suriyaa@gerrit.wikimedia.org:29418/operations/mediawiki-config
$ git pull origin master
$ git checkout -b suriyaakudocommits origin/master
$ git branch
$ git branch suriyaakudocommits --track origin/master
$ git checkout suriyaakudocommits
```

I editing a file and add it with `git add`:

```
$ git diff
$ git status
$ git add 404.html
$ git status
$ git diff --cached
$ git commit
$ git pull --rebase origin master
```

---

I used **`git review -R`** to commit my changes from my branch "`suriyaakudocommits`" to Wikimedia Gerrit (branch: "`master`") and I got this (error) output:

```
C:\Users\Suriyaa\Documents\GitHub\mediawiki-config [suriyaakudocommits]> git review -R
Using global/system git-review config files (C:\Users\Suriyaa/.config/git-review\git-review.conf) is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\git-review.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 1522, in main
    _main()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 1393, in _main
    config = Config(os.path.join(top_dir, ".gitreview"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 285, in __init__
    self.config.update(load_config_file(filename))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 671, in load_config_file
    configParser.read(config_file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 672, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1058, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\Users\\Suriyaa/.config/git-review\\git-review.conf', line: 1
'ï»¿[gerrit]\n'
```

> What's wrong? I hope someone can help me.
>
> I use *Python 3.4 (32 bit)*!
>
> I followed the [MediaWiki tutorial for Gerrit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Push_your_change_set_to_Gerrit).

---

The code of `C:\\Users\\Suriyaa/.config/git-review\\git-review.conf` file:

```
[gerrit]
defaultremote = origin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MediaWiki tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Configuring_git-review) you mentioned now says that the git-review.conf file is deprecated. Instead, you should use:

```
$ git config --global gitreview.remote origin
```

I also had to remove the .conf file to get rid of the warning.